# Find elements within dynamic table rows, avoid cache issues | Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, caching, dynamic, static

I need to find a way to go through each row of a table identified by class (rows are dynamic), looking for content in one column (static). If nothing matches, it will try again in some time. When it tries again, it is very likely the table has a different number of rows or a previously-found row in a different location.

How can I prevent against stuff like:

```
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

Here is an example of me finding the table by css selector, searching for text found in "last row" (Which I would rather scan all rows one at a time):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(name.MultiInstance.Updater, 10);
WebElement test1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr.eok:last-of-type > td > div")));
if (test1.getAttribute("title").contains("test1: Success"))
{
    isWarning();
}
else
{
    System.out.print("Radar: No Post-test1 Targets Found \r");
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML... and it would be nice if you properly indented your code to make it easier to read. :)

Comment: HTML code is not needed and is dynamic as posted. Just envision any table with rows. Except the table at hand adds/subtracts rows and some rows stay but move location.